# How to divide a number per zero using another informations

Tags: percentages

everyone is well? 
My background for this questions is:
I have a number of sent files, also I have a number of expectedly sendt files and finally the percentage of files, so I have: 
**sent/expected (percentage)**.

In my rules it's ok, if the user wants to send files without waiting for some, in other "numbers", for example, $\frac{24 \ \text{files}}{0 \ \ \text{files}}$ (percentage).

My question is, how can I calculate the percentage if no files are expected in this second case?

PS: I have a total count where is added all the number and made the percentage.

PS2: Sorry for my bad English, i'm brazilian and i do not have much english skills. :(

[image: My image with the problem]

Comment: Just decide what you want it to be. If you have sent no files out of zero expected files, should that be 0% sent? 100% sent? Its undefined mathematically

Comment: I tried to edit the grammar your question, please check if I understood everything correctly :)

Comment: @siegehalver So, i have no math trick to find this percentage? I thought about this possibility because in the total i have the number of sended files and the total of expected files and I was able to find the percentage, so i can find the 29/0 percentage too, is not that right?

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa  that's perfect. Tks a lot!!!

Comment: It is still a little unclear what you are doing, but in most applications a file is either (A) expected and sent, (B) expected but not sent, (C) sent but not expected, or (D) neither expected nor sent. If you take the ratio $100\% \times A/(A+B)$ then you have the percentage of expected files that were sent, and $100\% \times A/(A+C)$ is the percentage of sent files that were expected. I don't see any useful interpretation of $(A+B)/(A+C),$ though it might be interesting to track $(C - B)/(A+B+C).$

Comment: @DavidK With your explanation i think i resolved my doubt, tks! Turning everything with number into letters helped me understand the problem.